# Palindrome checker: list indexing confusion, how is this working?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop, indexing

I was trying to make a program that takes a string as an input and checks whether it is a palindrome.
I wrote this and it works but I'm confused as to how it works. Specifically, the list indexing when making the reverse list. Could someone please explain this step wise, I've been trying to follow it.
Now I'm wondering how I even wrote this then.

```
word = input("Enter a word. ")
letter_list = []

for i in word:
    letter_list.append(i)
print(letter_list)
reverse = []
len = len(letter_list)

for i in letter_list:
    reverse.insert(-(len - 1), i)
print(reverse)

if letter_list == reverse:
    print("This word is a palindrome.")
else:
    print("This word is not a palindrome.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [insert command](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) receives an index and an element to be inserted. The elements are shifted to the right in order to store the new element. Since the command

```
reverse.insert(-(len - 1), i)
```

in your code is always inserting the element *i* at the beginning of the new list *(- (len - 1)* (insertion of negative indexes goes through the end to the beginning), and *i* is varying from the beginning to the end of the original list *letter_list*,

```
for i in letter_list:
```

then the new list will contain the original reversed. Then you just compare to see whether they are equal.

```
letter_list == reverse
```

By the way, the command *reverse.insert(-(len - 1), i)* has the same effect as

```
reverse.insert(0, i)
```

You could use [this site](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) in order to follow the execution step by step.

Comment: So the index function shifts the existing elements to the right and then insert the given value? Does that mean it'll work the same way if I have positive (len -1) instead of the negative in the code?

Comment: Sorry, if you pass a negative code, it cross the list from the end to the beginning. The -(len-1) maximum index from the end to the beginning. It'd work the same way if you put a negative smaller than -(len-1). It'd work as always inserting in the beginning, i.e., *insert(0,i)*. I'll insert this note in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to make a program that takes a string as an input and checks whether it is a palindrome.

If you want to check if a word is palindrome you can do it in a very simple way:

```
>>> def is_palindrome(word):
...     return word == word[::-1]
...
>>> word = input("Enter a word: ")
Enter a word: kajak
>>> word
kajak
>>> is_palindrome(word)
True
>>>
```

`word[::-1]` returns `word` string in reverse.

But if you want to make it as for loop in a list of chars, then here is a code:

```
def is_palindrome(letters):
    l = len(letters)
    for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
        if letters[i] != letters[l-1 - i]:
            return False
    return True

letter_list = list(input("Enter a word: "))
print(is_palindrome(letter_list))
```

Result:

```
Enter a word: kajak
True
```

**I recommend you first method. It's much faster**

## Edit - Explanation

```
for i in word:
        letter_list.append(i)
```

`letter_list` is filled with every letter that user typed, e.g  for "kajak" is `['k', 'a', 'j', 'a', 'k']`.

```
for i in letter_list:
    reverse.insert(-(len - 1), i)
print(reverse)
```

Insert every letter from `letter_list` to `reverse` at index `-(len - 1)`.

```
if letter_list == reverse:
    print("This word is a palindrome.")
else:
    print("This word is not a palindrome.")
```

If lists are equal then print that word is palindrome. Else not.

**NOTE:*** You loop with `reverse` is wrong. You are constantly inserting a letter to the same position, which makes other words shift. It works, but it's not good. Also try not to name your variables with keywords (`len` is built-in function. You should do something as `letters_len = len(letter_list)`)

Comment: The first way is so useful. Thank you. But my question is more about how the code I wrote is working.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my post and try to explain it to you.